# Text recognition with tensorfow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ocr

I'm new to tensorflow and played around with the hand written numbers MNIST set.
I'd like to do my own project that recognises text instead of numbers but can't find a good tutorial.

Is it the same principle as numbers but instead of 10 layers at the end I have to use 26? Or include upper and lowercase and special characters?
If so I'd have to first crop the words into each character, right? Or is there a way to recognise entire sentences?

I'd like to train three different fonts, so no handwriting, and don't care about upper or lower case.

Later I'd like to use the trained model on photographs. A printed article for example. Does the model work if I align the image, do I have to retrain for a little bit or train it from the start with the new data?

Where do I start? The [Keras example](https://keras.io/examples/image_ocr/) is overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an OCR model, a simple CNN can't detect text from scanned images, you need to segment them first which can be completed based on the language script.

You can start with `tesseract`. There is a python wrapper named pytesseract.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("temp.jpg"), lang='eng',
                        config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

print(text)
```

For your own model, try CRNN models. https://github.com/qjadud1994/CRNN-Keras